# sql insert row, but return an item from that row

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, razor

Using c#, visual studio, razor html and asp.net, i have an orders table which saves a customer number to it in th ecustoemr_id, and it then autoincrements the order_id field, i need to select the order id of the row ive just inserted. i cannot just select all from that customer number, because there will be multiple order id's to customers. below is how i'm saving the customer id to the database, i need the order id from the row just created printed into a variable.
i've spent hours googling, and found answers for PHP but nothing using c# and asp.net
thanks in advance

```
string sql = "insert into orders (User_ID) values ('" + Request["UserID"] + "')";
var rst1 = db.Query(sql);
```

Comment: Why can't you use an IDENTITY column? What rdbms are you using at all?

Comment: The Order_ID is set as identity True, but i'd have no idea how to call that back and im just using the one thats built into visual studio, its what we've been told to use at college

Comment: Tell us the type of rdbms you are using, Linq, Entity Framework?

Comment: The best answer depends on your rdbms(f.e. MS SQL-Server or Oracle). In SQL-Server you could use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: Okay, how would I work that into my code?  it says Microsoft SQL Server Compact when i go to the database properties.

Comment: What's with these colleges teaching students how to write code that's susceptible to SQL Injection? Second one in as many days. You should be using command parameters, not trying to build a string for your SQL statement.

Comment: This is the way my lecturer has asked for it to be done though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] (id) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (id value)";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, dbconnection);
string value;
value = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Read  here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to SCOPE_IDENTITY is OUTPUT. Something like:

```
DECLARE @OrderOutput TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL)
insert into orders (User_ID) 
OUTPUT Inserted.OrderId INTO @OrderOutput(ID)
values ('" + Request["UserID"] + "')"
SELECT ID from @OrderOutput
```

Comment: How would i work that into my code though? we've only been taught how to run simple sql commands like the one in the op

Comment: You can use that as your string instead of your insert statement. The value of rst1 would be the ID from @OrderOutput.

Comment: Is there any chance you can work it into my code from the op? I've tried copying what you've said in, but we've only been taught a very basic level of SQL, its going above my head